# My javafx app loads fast but fxml takes time to initialize

Tags: javafx-2, fxml

My javafx app is taking a long time to initialize fxml controls .I tried using the preloader but since the application loads fast and then takes time during the initialization phase the preloader is of no use to me.... i see a transparent frame with no content after the execution of preloader for about 2 sec and then the controlls seems to apear...i tried taking the screenshot of the frame using printscreen but in the screenshot all controlls are visible... can anyone tell me what the problem is and what should i do..?

[Screenshot](http://www.flickr.com/photos/shashankips/8555457155/in/photostream)

Comment: Please post some code.

Answer (score 1):

If you've found a performance issue, you can file it here:

http://javafx-jira.kenai.com

It would be great if you could provide a sample which shows the issue.